# Avoid running GNU make recipe when prerequisite is updated

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that looks like this:

```
foo: bar                                                                                                                                
        touch foo
        sleep 2
        echo UPDATED > bar

bar: baz
        cp baz bar
        sleep 2
```

`bar` does not initially exist so it is copied from `baz`.  However, a side-effect of building `foo` is that `bar` is also modified such that its timestamp might be newer than that of `foo`.  Is there a way around this?  Would order-only dependencies help somehow?

In addition, if baz is later modified, bar and foo would need rebuilding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**

It is enough to `touch foo` just after `bar` has been updated.  In this way, `foo` is always newer than `bar`.

```
foo: bar                                                                                                                                
        sleep 2
        echo UPDATED > bar
        touch foo

bar: baz
        cp baz bar
        sleep 2
```

**SOLUTION 2**

An order-only prerequisites, such as

```
foo: | bar                                                                                                                                
    touch foo
    sleep 2
    echo UPDATED > bar

bar: baz
    cp baz bar
    sleep 2
```

will do, too; but keep in mind that order-only prerequisites are a GNU extension to the syntax of `Makefile`, hence not fully portable.

**EDIT**

If, in addition, you want `bar` and `foo` to be rebuilt when `baz` is modified, then the only feasible solution is the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you need `bar` to exist for `foo` but don't need to rebuild `foo` just because `bar` changes then an order-only prerequisite sounds like what you want.

You could also possibly just `touch foo` at the end of the rule instead and avoid this 'foo causes itself to get rebuilt next time' problem entirely, assuming that is workable in this environment.

Comment: I've added another condition at the end of my question.  The problem I see with order-only dependency is that, if baz is modified, foo will not be rebuilt.

Comment: Correct, you can't have your cake and eat it to unfortunately. That's why I offered the second option (mirrored by @RobertoReale in his answer) of simply ensuring that you touch your target last in your rule body thus avoiding this problem.